# AzureDataFactory - 403 Forbidden With an Odata linked service

Tags: azure-data-factory, olap

Azure Data Factory
Linked Service: OData
Integration Runtime: Local network
Target: Microsoft Project Odata (hosted in the same local network)

I've got a 403 - Forbidden error while I try to reach my Microsoft Project Odata target..

[Odata Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzYmK.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ58v.png)

Whereas, it works when I do the same link with the Odata connector in Visual Studio (inside a SSAS Project for example).

I already test the network link between the server who host the integration runtime and my target point. It's ok.

Do you have an idea?

Regards,

I already test the network link beetween the server who host the integration runtime and my target point. It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the 403 (Forbidden Error) , so my best guess is that you are not authenticated .
I also see and the you are using domain\username for authentication with Windows authentication . I think you you should try out username@yourcompanyname.com and see if that works.